# Calculadora utilizando Socket em Java

Tags: java, socket

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade e peguei algumas informações da Internet, o professor pediu um cliente que envie 2 valores e uma operação básica, o servidor deve pegar isso e retornar o total. Acontece que o cliente só pega as variáveis dele mesmo, não pega o total que vem do servidor e nem o `opr` que é o simbolo da operação.

```
public class Servidor2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int num1, num2, total = 0;
        int operacao = 0;
        char opr = 0;

        //Cria um socket na porta 12342
        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12342);
        System.out.println("Porta 12342 aberta!");

        // Aguarda alguém se conectar. A execução do servidor
        // fica bloqueada na chamada do método accept da classe
        // ServerSocket. Quando alguém se conectar ao servidor, o
        // método desbloqueia e retorna com um objeto da classe
        // Socket, que é uma porta da comunicação.

        System.out.print("Aguardando conexão do cliente...");
        Socket cliente = servidor.accept();

        System.out.println("Nova conexao com o cliente " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());


        ObjectOutputStream resultado = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream dados = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

        num1 = dados.readInt();
        num2 = dados.readInt();

        operacao = dados.readInt();
        if (operacao == 1) {

            opr = '+';
            total = (num1 + num2);


        }
        if (operacao == 2) {

            opr = '-';
            total = (num1 - num2);
        }
        if (operacao == 3) {


            opr = 'x';
            total = (num1 * num2);
        }
        if (operacao == 4) {


            opr = '/';
            total = (num1 / num2);
        } else {


            System.out.printf("Você digitou uma operação inválida.");

        }

        resultado.writeInt(total);
        resultado.writeChar(opr);
        resultado.flush();
        resultado.flush();
        servidor.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class Cliente2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int operacao = 0;
        char opr;
        Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12342);
        System.out.println("O cliente conectou ao servidor");


        ObjectInputStream resultado = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream dados = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());


        num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o primeiro número"));
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o segundo número"));
        operacao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual operação desejada? 1= +, 2= -,3= X,4= / "));
        dados.writeInt(operacao);
        dados.writeDouble(num1);
        dados.writeDouble(num2);

        dados.flush();

        int total = resultado.readInt();
        opr = resultado.readChar();
        System.out.println("Total de " + num1 + opr + num2 + " = " + total);

        cliente.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja o [tour], se acha que o objetivo principal desta pergunta foi alcançado você pode aceitar a resposta. Também poderá votar em tudo no site que achar útil, não só nas coisas ligadas aos seus posts.

Answer (score 1):

O problema no seu código está na hora de enviar e receber os dados, no cliente você está usando:

```
dados.writeInt(operacao);
dados.writeDouble(num1);
dados.writeDouble(num2);
```

E no servidor:

```
num1 = dados.readInt();
num2 = dados.readInt();
operacao = dados.readInt();
```

Dois problemas são notados aqui, o primeiro seria o fato de você estar enviando um  `Double` e querer receber um `Integer`, e o outro seria a ordem que os dados são enviados e recebidos, pois no cliente você envia `operacao`, `num1` e `num2`, e no servidor você está recebendo `num1`, `num2` e `operacao`, o fato das variáveis terem o mesmo nome não significa nada nesse caso.

Para resolver seu problema, ajuste as duas classes com `Integer` ou com `Double` e coloque a mesma ordem de envio e recebimento, vou postar como ficaria utilizando `Double`.

```
public class Servidor2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double num1, num2, total = 0.0;
        int operacao;
        char opr = '\n';

        //Cria um socket na porta 12342
        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12342);
        System.out.println("Porta 12342 aberta!");

        // Aguarda alguém se conectar. A execução do servidor
        // fica bloqueada na chamada do método accept da classe
        // ServerSocket. Quando alguém se conectar ao servidor, o
        // método desbloqueia e retorna com um objeto da classe
        // Socket, que é uma porta da comunicação.

        System.out.print("Aguardando conexão do cliente...");
        Socket cliente = servidor.accept();

        System.out.println("Nova conexao com o cliente " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());


        ObjectOutputStream resultado = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream dados = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

        operacao = dados.readInt();
        num1 = dados.readDouble();
        num2 = dados.readDouble();

        if (operacao == 1) {

            opr = '+';
            total = (num1 + num2);

        } else if (operacao == 2) {

            opr = '-';
            total = (num1 - num2);

        } else if (operacao == 3) {

            opr = 'x';
            total = (num1 * num2);

        } else {

            opr = '/';
            total = (num1 / num2);

        }

        resultado.writeDouble(total);
        resultado.writeChar(opr);
        resultado.flush();

        resultado.close();
        dados.close();
        servidor.close();
    }
}
```

> **Nota:** nesse caso você pode utilizar `if` e `else if` ao invés de somente `if`, isso evita verificações desnecessárias dependendo do valor de `opr`.
>   **Nota 2:** a validação da operação fica mais fácil de ser feita direto no cliente.
>   **Nota 3:** não é necessário utilizar `resultado.flush();` duas vezes.

```
public class Cliente2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        double num1;
        double num2;
        int operacao = 0;
        char opr;
        Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12342);
        System.out.println("O cliente conectou ao servidor");


        ObjectInputStream resultado = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream dados = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());


        num1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o primeiro número"));
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o segundo número"));
        while (!((operacao >= 1) && (operacao <= 4))) {
            operacao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual operação desejada? 1= +, 2= -,3= X,4= / "));
            if (!((operacao >= 1) && (operacao <= 4))) {
                System.out.println("Você digitou uma operação inválida.");
            }
        }
        dados.writeInt(operacao);
        dados.writeDouble(num1);
        dados.writeDouble(num2);
        dados.flush();

        double total = resultado.readDouble();
        opr = resultado.readChar();
        System.out.println("Total de " + num1 + opr + num2 + " = " + total);

        resultado.close();
        dados.close();
        cliente.close();
    }
}
```

> **Nota:** a validação feita consiste em um loop que verifica se a operação digitada está em 1 e 4, caso não esteja, imprime no console e solicita novamente a operação para o usuário.

Comment: Mateus, fiz as alterações que você disse, mas continua sem funcionar as operações, ele retorna os números digitados, porém não faz a operação e nem retorna o simbolo da operação, acredito que não esteja pegando os dados retornados pelo servidor, não sei debugar isso, to apanhando desde muito cedo hoje pra fazer isso.

Comment: você recebe algum erro? Eu testei com a seguinte entrada `40`, `2` e `4`, o resultado foi `O cliente conectou ao servidor    Total de 40.0/2.0 = 20.0`, qual IDE está usando?

Comment: Mateus, estou utilizando o Eclipse Luna, não recebo nenhum erro, ele me retorna isso no console  'O cliente conectou ao servidor
Total de 40.0
20.0 = 0.0'

Comment: dê  uma olhada na classe `Servidor2`, você corrigiu a ordem para `operacao = dados.readInt(); num1 = dados.readInt(); num2 = dados.readInt();`?

Comment: Mateus, realmente, era isso o que estava errado, agradeço muito a ajuda. Agora tenho outra questão a quebrar a cabeça.Sobre threads, 2 usuários se conectando.

Comment: @brenoguto, você realmente precisa trabalhar com threads? Fazer um `while` na classe `Servidor2` para ficar recebendo os clientes não te atenderia?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19242/discussion-between-brenoguto-and-mateus-alexandre).